# JenkinAPI error with server.get_jobs "max retries exceeded with url"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-api

From the beginning of the new year, i cannot extract jobs info from my Jenkins, using the classic example that can be found here: https://jenkinsapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using_jenkinsapi.html#example-2-get-details-of-jobs-running-on-jenkins-server. In replace of them, i get the following error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=,
> port=): Max retries exceeded with url:
> /job/<JOB_NAME>/api/python?tree=allBuilds%5Bnumber%2Curl%5D (Caused by
> ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host=, port=): Read
> timed out. (read timeout=10)"))

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if the host you are connecting to is not available.

I would suggest trying a few network tests to ensure the host is visible:
where:
ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myhost.something.com', port=1234)

try netcat or tracepath:
-> nc  -w  5  -vz  myhost.something.com  1234

    Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )

    Ncat: Connected to 10.11.12.13:1234.

    Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.01 seconds.

-> tracepath -p 33434 myhost.something.com